# Remove double quotes within double quotes

Tags: mysql, csv, sed, load-data-infile

I want to import a large CSV file using MySQL load data infile, file delimited with pipe `|`, enclosed with double quotes `""`. Many fields are text data with double quotes inside double quotes and I get all data in the same column, so I need to remove extra double quotes only if contain within quotes:

Example:

```
|"George Kastrioti "Skanderbeg""|""|""|"1926"|
```

Desired output:

```
|"George Kastrioti Skanderbeg"|"|"|"1926"|
```

Tried with `sed` but with no real success, any ideas or tips?

Comment: This isn't valid CSV, wouldn't it make more sense to try and fix the source?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ': again
s/\(|"[^"|]*\)"\([^"|]*"\)/\1\2/g
t again
s/""/"/g' YourFile
```

but i imagine that `|""|` is more logic than `|"|` so this version should be better (just an idea, don't know your real need and your sample state 1 double quote only for empty value)

```
sed ': again
s/\(|"[^"|]*\)"\([^"|]*"\)/\1\2/g
t again' YourFile
```

Comment: What to do if input appear like as |"This is the |"First" column"|"This is the "Second" column"|"This is the "Third" column".|"This is the |"First" column"|  what to do '|'  come inside